# PriviledgedActionException Failed to set permissions of path

Tags: windows, hadoop, mahout

I have windows without cygwin and unit test for mahout, and this test start hadoop job during it i have next exception:

> Jul 9, 2013 5:21:23 AM org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader 
>   WARNING: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>   Jul 9, 2013 5:21:23 AM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
>   INFO: Build Clusters Input: file:/tmp/mahout1-TestClusterDumper-3279087666375853056/testdata Out: file:/tmp/mahout1-TestClusterDumper-3279087666375853056/output Measure: org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure@62c8769b t1: 8.0 t2: 4.0
>   Jul 9, 2013 5:21:24 AM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
>   INFO: Input: file:/tmp/mahout1-TestClusterDumper-3279087666375853056/testdata Clusters In: file:/tmp/mahout1-TestClusterDumper-3279087666375853056/output/clusters-0-final Out: file:/tmp/mahout1-TestClusterDumper-3279087666375853056/output/kmeans Distance: org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure
>   Jul 9, 2013 5:21:24 AM org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerAdapter info
>   INFO: convergence: 0.0010 max Iterations: 10
>
> java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mahout\mahout\integration\target\mahout-TestClusterDumper-5458229048736903168\hadoop0.5515906057710666\mapred\staging\Administrator-585933322.staging to 0700
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:662)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
>   ...
>
> Jul 9, 2013 5:21:24 AM org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation doAs
>   SEVERE: PriviledgedActionException as:Administrator cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mahout\mahout\integration\target\mahout-TestClusterDumper-5458229048736903168\hadoop0.5515906057710666\mapred\staging\Administrator-585933322.staging to 0700

I can't use cygwin!

Answer (score 4):

Windows and Hadoop don't really like each other, but if I remember correctly it had something to do more with the JVM. This is a known issue of Hadoop since versions above 0.22.0, although I'm uncertain whether it has been fixed in the most recent versions.

There is/was a workaround, but when I encountered this issue as well, I remember it was quite convoluted.

I suggest you use a linux (virtual) machine for using Mahout with Hadoop.

Oh! There's a hadoop ticket ([link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7682)) discussing the issue.

I also found this ([link](https://github.com/congainc/patch-hadoop_7682-1.0.x-win))

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. Hadoop on windows is most of the times a mess.